# Template by method pointer in clang vs gcc and msvc

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, gcc, clang

I have this function:

```c
template <typename T, void (T::*pf)()>
void call(T& t)
{
    (t.*pf)();
}
```

If I have class `foo` with a method with the appropriate signature (say `bar`) I can call it like this `call<foo, &foo::bar>();` and it's fine. However if `bar` is `const` gcc and msvc are happy to compile it when called like this `call<const foo, &foo::bar>()`. Clang complains that the second template parameter is invalid. When I put `const` in the template arguments (`void (T::*pf)() const`) all tree compile it.

Now, this is not a huge issue, but my code becomes much much cleaner if I don't have to write this wretched `const` in the template arguments.

So the question basically is: What does the standard say about this? Is this a clang bug or are gcc and msvc just letting it slide because they're cool like that?

PS Here's a link to a complete repro program: http://codepad.org/wDBdGvSN

Comment: Clang is right here, the type of a pointer to const-qualified member function is `R (C::*)(Args) const` and can't be converted to a non-const one.

Comment: But I guess you might say that `R (C::*)(Args) const` is the same as this (invalid but understandable): `R (const C::*)(Args)`

Comment: No, it's not exactly the same. The former version can still be called perfectly fine on a non-const `C` object.

Comment: You can call a const function on a non const object, so these are not strictly equvalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `const`-ness of a method is part of the 'signature' of it. So, the proper way to define and use a pointer to member is:

```
R (Obj::*)(Args)       // for non-const member
R (Obj::*)(Args) const // for const member
```

Note that a `const` member can be called on a non-const object, which is not the case with `R (const Obj::*)(Args)`.

A way to solve this is to abstract such function pointers, by defining 'call wrappers':

```
template<typename O, void (O::* f)()>
struct NonConstFunc
{
    static void call(O* o)
    {
        (o->*f)();
    }
};

template<typename O, void (O::* f)() const>
struct ConstFunc
{
    static void call(O* o)
    {
        (o->*f)();
    }
};
```

Then, you can use it the following way (here the abstraction takes place):

```
template<typename Obj, typename Function>
void call(Obj* o)
{
    Function::call(o);
}
```

There is a [live example here](http://codepad.org/gfwwrrzt).

This is just the main idea. You can extend it with automatic detection of whether the method is `const` or not, without changing the user code.

Comment: I ended up doing something very similar. Thanks.